# This program does not work from terminal but works in zerobrane

Tags: terminal, lua, emacs, zerobrane

```
x = 10
io.write("Enter the name of the variable you want to be printed: ")
index = io.read()
f = loadstring("return " ..  index)
print(f())
```

The above code gives this error when used in a terminal, but not when ran in zerobrane studio

```
main.lua:874: attempt to call a nil value (global 'loadstring') 
stack traceback: 
    main.lua:874: in main chunk [C]: in ?
```

This is important because i am coding lua in emacs.
how can i correct this problem? Need help.

Comment: Describe how doesn't it work. Does it close after you enter something?

Comment: it gives this error which does not exit in zerobrane: "lua: main.lua:874: attempt to call a nil value (global 'loadstring')
stack traceback:
 main.lua:874: in main chunk
 [C]: in ?"

Comment: Lua you use from the terminal is probably Lua 5.3 or higher. `loadstring` was deprecated in Lua 5.2 and removed in 5.3. Verify your version using `lua -v`

Comment: Lua 5.3.3. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Your terminal version of Lua is higher than Lua in ZeroBrane.

Lua 5.3 removed `loadstring` and it exists as `load` now.